# C# & EF Core : problem updating an entity in relational database

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I have the following entities:

```
public class WorkflowTemplate
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }

    public List<TemplateStep>? WorkflowSteps { get; set; }
}

public class TemplateStep
{
    [ForeignKey("WorkflowTemplate")]
    public Guid WorkflowTemplateId { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public WorkflowTemplate? WorkflowTemplate { get; set; }

    public ICollection<TemplateStepCondition>? Conditions { get; set; }
}

public class TemplateStepCondition
{
    public Guid TemplateStepId { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public TemplateStep? TemplateStep { get; set; }

    public Guid ConditionId { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public Condition? Condition { get; set; }

    public ConditionType ConditionType { get; set; }
}

public class Condition
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public ICollection<TemplateStepCondition>? TemplateSteps { get; set; }
}
```

Now I am trying to update a `WorkflowTemplate` entity using EF Core, but I'm getting the following error:

> The instance of entity type 'Condition' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 0000000-0000-00000-000000}'*(GUID changed by me)* is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

I have tried the following approach:

```
public void UpdateWorkflowTemplate(WorkflowTemplate updatedWorkflowTemplate)
{
   var existingTemplate = await _unitOfWork.WorkflowTemplates
                                           .GetByIdAsync(templateDetails.Id);

   _mapper.Map(templateDetails, existingTemplate);

   _unitOfWork.WorkflowTemplates.Update(existingTemplate);
   var result = _unitOfWork.Save();
 }
```

Please suggest the correct way to handle such situation and suggest best practice for updating entities with EF Core.

Comment: Automapper itself do now update collections correctly, use [AutoMapper.Collection](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection) package. Also do not call `Update`, it is not needed.

Comment: You must use foreignkey attribute to field conditionId

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Can you elaborate the use of Automapper regarding the above context?

Comment: @abolfazlsadeghi I have baseEntity which has ID and I am assigning it as a foreign key in DataContext. So that is already taken care of.

Comment: Please post the missing code. It's quite possible any problems are caused by the extra "unit of work"  EF Core's DbContext already is a Unit-of-Work, it doesn't need another wrapper. `DbContext.Update` isn't needed with objects loaded through DbContext. The DbContext will detect all changes to them and their related objects.

Comment: `is already taken care of.` we can't tell that. In fact, the error you posted is often *caused* by the unnecessary "repositories" and "units of work" people put over the existing Unit-of-Work class, DbContext. In this case I'd guess the `Condition`'s PK isn't configured to be database-generated, and the code tried to attach multiple objects with the default PK value using `Update`. EF correctly complains there are existing objects with the same ID already in memory

Comment: @JayVansjalia, for correct updating child collections EF Core expects that you update all child entities one by one. It is not what Automapper do, it creates new child collection and EF fails. It has to know `Id` mapping between DTO and Entity, find existing item in target collection and update properties.

Comment: Somehow, the code ended up creating 2 or more `Condition` objects with the same `ID` value and tried to attach them to the DbContext. Even another developer couldn't decide what to do here - replace the previous object? Discard the new object? Update the old with the new values?